# Sorted list vs heap: Deleting elements in the middle of the list Python

Tags: python-3.x, list, performance, heap

I have a list structure updated continiously. In every iteration the following steps are performed:

- Delete minimum value in the list
- delete n values somewhere in the list
- add n values to the list

As far as i understood a heap is not a good solution here (even with lazy deletes) because i need to delete values somewhere in the list for which i dont know the index (position). Thus these values needs to be searched..

Do I just use a sorted list for this problem? I need the best performance I can get here since the list is up to 100.000 elements at some point in the loop.

Comment: How do you identify the n values to be deleted?

Comment: it is raster and if there is a new value calculated which is lower than the previous one the item in the list is replaced by the new value

Answer (score 1):

If the values can be used as dict keys, then it would be pretty easy to use both a heap, and a `collections.Counter` to keep track of how many of each value is conceptually still in the collection.  A count of 0 means the value has conceptually been deleted entirely, although it may still exist in the heap.

Here's a sketch (untested!), where `c` is an instance of `collections.Counter` and `h` is a list used as the heap for the `heapq` module's operations:

To add an element (expected-case time logarithmic in heap size):

```
heapq.heappush(h, elt)
c[elt] += 1
```

To delete an element (expected-case constant time):

```
if not c[elt]:
    raise ValueError("element doesn't exist")
c[elt] -= 1
if not c[elt]:
    del c[elt]
```

To delete minimum element (expected-case logarithmic time (in the shrinking size of the heap) for each *conceptually* already-deleted item popped from the heap):

```
while True:
    if not h:
        raise ValueError("cannot find minimum in empty collection")
    elt = heapq.heappop(h)
    if c[elt]:
        c[elt] -= 1
        if not c[elt]:
            del c[elt]
        break
    # else the Counter believes it was deleted earlier
```

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the issue of not knowing the index of the item to be deleted by also maintaining a dictionary alongside the heap. The values in the dictionary are the same as the heap items (perhaps a list with a priority value and a reference to the real item). The dictionary keys are the same as the real items, so they're easy to look up.

When you want to delete an item that is not the minimum, you look it up in the dictionary and mark it as deleted (perhaps by setting the reference to the item to `None`). No need to modify the list representing the heap, it has references to the same items, so it will see that the item was deleted whenever it comes up to be removed as the minimum.

That said, if you are doing the "delete items from anywhere in the data" operation frequently, then you might be better served with just a regular dictionary or set. You can get the minimum with `min` in linear time, and removals (of any item, including the minimum) takes constant time (amortized, on average). For some usage patterns that might be faster than dealing with a heap.